# Convert C to ARM Assembly program

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I have this C program:

```
void Move1Disk(int fm, int to);

void Hanoi(int num, int fm, int to, int aux)
{
    if (num > 1) Hanoi(num - 1, fm, aux, to) ;
    Move1Disk(fm, to) ;
    if (num > 1) Hanoi(num - 1, aux, to, fm) ;
}
```

I have written this but can not compile, can anyone please tell me the issue?

```
Hanoi(int, int, int, int):
        cmp     r0, #1
        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, lr}
        mov     r5, r1
        mov     r7, r2
        movgt   r4, r0
        movgt   r6, r3
        ble     .L9
.L3:
        sub     r4, r4, #1
        mov     r0, r4
        mov     r3, r7
        mov     r2, r6
        mov     r1, r5
        bl      Hanoi(int, int, int, int)
        mov     r1, r7
        mov     r0, r5
        bl      Move1Disk(int, int)
        cmp     r4, #1
        beq     .L2
        mov     r3, r5
        mov     r5, r6
        mov     r6, r3
        b       .L3
.L9:
        mov     r6, r1
.L2:
        mov     r1, r7
        mov     r0, r6
        pop     {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, lr}
        b       Move1Disk(int, int)
```

here I have included the main [main method](https://www.engr.scu.edu/%7Edlewis/book3/labs/Lab5dMain.c)

and a picture of the error message:
[image: [error message]]

Comment: "I have written this but can not compile"  Q: Please update your post: 1) copy/paste the exact error messasge, 2) indicate the line the error occurs on.  PS: C or Java programs "compile"; an assembler program "assembles" ;)

Comment: I have updated sir

Comment: You can take a look here how it is converted to ARM ASM (this one is for v7a): https://godbolt.org/z/5zY5dM

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not code if possible.

Comment: The code you've posted is clearly compiler output and, besides the demangling issue, seems to be generated for a different instruction set than the one you're expected to use (cortex-m4 and thumb).  So if you want it to work, try `-mcpu=cortex-m4` when compiling.

Comment: By the way, if this is an assignment where you're expected to write the assembly code by hand, and you're planning to turn in compiler output instead, you should know that it's really obvious and you will get caught.

Answer (score 1):

On the very first line:

```
Hanoi(int, int, int, int):
```

C functions don't have their argument types as part of their names.  If you really are trying to duplicate a C program, this should just be `Hanoi:`.  The same for all other instances of that and of `Move1Disk`.

Comment: I am new in Assembly sir, can u please help me to modify it.

Comment: Get rid of all the `(...)` stuff after function names.

Comment: @SouravPal: on https://godbolt.org/ where you copy-pasted compiler output from, uncheck the "demangle C++" option so label names will be real label names that actually work as asm.  Or compile as C instead of C++, e.g. by using the `-xc` command-line option, or switching the language dropdown.